# MySQL - Select unique column with max timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to prepare a query and I'm having a hard time with it. I need some MySQL gurus to help please...

Take the following table as an example...

`CREATE TABLE order_revision (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  parent_order_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  sub_total decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  tax_total decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  status smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  created_at int(11) NOT NULL,
  updated_at int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)`

I need a query to select all unique 'parent_order_id' with the max 'updated_at' value. This query should return all rows that have unique 'parent_order_id's based on the max timestamp of the 'updated_at' column.

In other words, each row returned should have an unique 'parent_order_id' and be the maximum timestamp of the'updated_at' column.

Basically this query would find the latest "order revision" for each "parent order"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, this query turned out to be the one I was looking for...

`SELECT main.*
FROM order_revision AS main
WHERE main.id = (
    SELECT sub.id
    FROM order_revision AS sub
    WHERE main.parent_order_id = sub.parent_order_id
    ORDER BY sub.updated_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
);`

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
SELECT parent_order_id,max(updated_at) FROM order_revision GROUP BY parent_order_id
```

For MySQL, the `GROUP BY`-clause isn't even necessary, nevertheless I would include it for clarification (and most other SQL-conform servers require it).

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. It works perfectly. I will mark this answer as correct as soon as the timer lets me.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake... This was very close but the order_revision ID's are not what I expected when I add the "id" column to the select clause. It is returning the first one available not the one with the max timestamp.

Comment: I think if I do this, it will work...

 SELECT max(id), parent_order_id ,max(updated_at) FROM order_revision GROUP BY parent_order_id

Comment: This will only work, if the maximum id is always coincident with the maximum value of updated_at.  Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Is there any other way to achieve what I'm looking to do? I need the entire row to be the correct row.

Comment: This depends on the relation between id and updated_at. If the pairing of parent_order_id and id is unique, `SELECT id,parent_order_id,max(updated_at) FROM order_revision GROUP BY parent_order_id,id` will do what you need

Comment: Thanks for your help Ctx, it put me on the right direction. The answer I posted below seems to be the query that I am looking for.